# Rails 5: param is missing or the value is empty: verbalquestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been working at this for hours with no solution. Whenenever I load the resource of a new `verbalquestion`, and I fill out the form and hit submit, i get an error of: `ActionController::ParameterMissing at /verbalquestions
param is missing or the value is empty: verbalquestions`

**verbalquestions_controller.rb**

```
class VerbalquestionsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
@verbalquestions = Verbalquestion.all

if params[:tag]
  @verbalquestions = Verbalquestion.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
   @verbalquestions = Verbalquestion.all
  end
  end 

  def new
    @title = "Add a new VQ"
  end

 def show
   @verbalquestion = Verbalquestion.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

def create
  @verbalquestion = Verbalquestion.new(verbalquestion_params)
  @verbalquestion.user = current_user

end
 end

private
  def verbalquestion_params
   params.require(:verbalquestions).
    permit(
    :vq_title,
    :vq_text,
    :tag_list
  )

end
```

**verbalquestions/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with scope: :verbalquestion, url: verbalquestions_path do |f| %>

<div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :tag_list, 'Tags (separated by commas)' %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>


<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Verbal Question Title", :class=>'label' %>
  <div class="control">
    <%= f.text_field :vq_title, :id => 'vq_title', :class => 'textarea' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Verbal Question Test", :class=>'label' %>
  <div class="control">
    <%= f.text_area :vq_text, :id => 'vq_text', :class => 'textarea' %>
  </div>
</div>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>


  <% end %>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your controller requires 'verbalquestions' in params
`params.require(:verbalquestions)`

You can try `form_for @verbalquestion` in your view and `@verbalquestion = Verbalquestion.new()` in `controller>new`.

Also, `params.require(:verbalquestions)` should be in a singular form like `params.require(:verbalquestion)`.

Comment: But the controller has the params set like this: `private
  def verbalquestion_params
    params.require(:verbalquestions).
      permit(
        :vq_title,
        :vq_text,
        :tag_list
      )

  end`

Also, form_for doesn't do anything as it is a rails 5.1 app. What should I do?

Comment: As I've already replied, add `@verbalquestion = Verbalquestion.new()` to your controller 'new' method.
Also, you can use `form_for @verbalquestion` in your view or `form_with model: @verbalquestion` on your choice.

Comment: I have done all of that and it doesn't work. It still says `ActionController::ParameterMissing at /verbalquestions
param is missing or the value is empty: verbalquestions`

Comment: Oh, it should be `params.require(:verbalquestion)`. Singular form. You can check logs how your parameters has been passed.